# Connecting to OpenVPN though a PPTP VPN on Yosemite

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pptp, osx-yosemite

I have just updated to Mac OS X Yosemite and the problem is that the traffic doesn't route to OpenVPN or Kerio connection behind a PPTP connection. Mavericks OS X does not have a problem.
I can also connect and properly use OpenVPN in other places which doesn't require connecting to PPTP VPNs first.
I somehow thought that the problem is with the routing table. So, here is my `netstat -rn` results while connecting to PPTP and Kerio:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                10.253.24.1        UGSc            0        0  kvnet0
default            link#12            UCS             7        0    ppp0
default            192.168.12.1       UGScI           3        0     en0
default            192.168.89.1       UGScI           2        0     en1
default            link#10            UCSI           13        0  kvnet0
1.1.1.52           172.17.21.183      UH              0        0    ppp0
1.1.1.55           192.168.12.1       UGHS            1      703     en0
2.16.100.43        44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        3  kvnet0   1183
8.8.4.4            44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        7  kvnet0   1188
8.8.8.8            44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWI           0        8  kvnet0   1186
10.253.24/21       link#10            UCS             3        0  kvnet0
10.253.24.1        44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIir         5        0  kvnet0   1185
10.253.31.255      link#10            UHLWbI          0        1  kvnet0
17.110.226.143     44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        1  kvnet0   1188
17.158.52.47       44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        2  kvnet0   1186
17.172.238.205     44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        2  kvnet0   1188
17.253.6.243       44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        1  kvnet0   1184
31.13.66.1         44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          3        4  kvnet0   1187
54.93.38.57        44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        3  kvnet0   1183
54.197.253.158     44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        1  kvnet0   1192
74.125.71.109      44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWI           0        3  kvnet0   1186
74.125.133.108     44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        8  kvnet0   1185
74.125.133.109     44:45:53:53:23:0   UHLWIi          1        8  kvnet0   1185
```

Here is my netstat output while not connecting to pppt connection and using kerio:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                10.253.24.1        UGSc            0        0  kvnet0
default            192.168.12.1       UGSc           10        0     en0
default            192.168.89.1       UGScI           1        0     en1
default            link#10            UCSI            6        0  kvnet0
a2-16-100-43.deplo 44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWIi          1       13  kvnet0   1200
google-public-dns- 44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWIi          2        6  kvnet0   1195
10.253.24/21       link#10            UCS             1        0  kvnet0
10.253.24.1        link#10            UHLWIir         4        0  kvnet0
time.apple.com     44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWIi          1        1  kvnet0   1197
edge-star-shv-01-d 44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWIi          1       22  kvnet0   1195
hosted-by.leaseweb 192.168.12.1       UGHS            2      175     en0
74.125.71.108      44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWIi          3       65  kvnet0   1196
74.125.71.109      44:45:53:53:21:0   UHLWI           0       21  kvnet0   1194
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH             12  2735894     lo0
128.0/1            10.253.24.1        UGSc            2        0  kvnet0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
169.254            link#5             UCSI            0        0     en1
192.168.12         link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.12.1/32    link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.12.1       0:7:e9:e:45:a6     UHLWIir         3      105     en0    747
192.168.12.157/32  link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.12.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        8     en0
192.168.89         link#5             UCS             6        0     en1
192.168.89.1/32    link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.89.1       a4:18:75:40:42:43  UHLWIir         3      303     en1   1182
192.168.89.12      0:16:e6:4c:99:7d   UHLWI           0       18     en1    872
192.168.89.31      8:0:27:10:79:9a    UHLWI           0        0     en1   1108
192.168.89.38      b8:88:e3:a4:2a:f2  UHLWIi          1       11     en1   1045
192.168.89.61/32   link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.89.61      e4:ce:8f:4:a7:d2   UHLWIi          1        2     lo0
192.168.89.64      90:a4:de:89:2:46   UHLWIi          1       13     en1    765
192.168.89.107     0:80:c8:f7:79:a4   UHLWI           0       18     en1    867
192.168.89.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        8     en1
```

Comment: You said you can't connect to kerio over pptp in yosemite, and yet here you are connected to kerio over pptp? What doesn't work in osx-yosemite? What have you tried? Can you traceroute to 8.8.8.8 in all configurations and what are the results of that on osx-yosemite?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Sorry, my bad. I can connect to both OpenVPN and Kerio behind the PPTP VPN. However, the traffic doesn't route to OpenVPN or kerio connection. When I check my outgoing IP, I see that it is still the IP address of my PPTP connection.